# Apple's iAd sample code throwing errors

Tags: iphone, ipad, iad

i am trying to incorporate iAd's into my app and in the process i'v gone through Apple's sample code.[This is the link to the sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdInterstitialSuite/Introduction/Intro.html). I have downloaded the sample code from apple's developer website and ran the same code without any changes in x-code. I encountered almost 9 errors after this,some of which are as follows.

1 - cannot find protocol declaration for iAdinterstitialAdDelegate

2 - ADInterstitialAd undeclared etc..

Please note that i haven't made any changes after downloading the code... Any help in this regard would really be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the SDK 4.3 (or newer) installed?
If yes, check the base SDK of your project/target and see if it's set to something lower than 4.3.

`ADInterstitialAd` is only available since 4.3

Comment: @jilouc: Currently i am using X-code 3.2.5 and my sdk is 4.2. Can i upgrade to sdk 4.3 by keeping my x-code version unchanged?? If so, can you please tell me the process to do it.... Thanks for ur help jilouc...

Comment: how can i check if it links or not??? I have added iAd framework to the code... is there something more that i should check?

Comment: @A for Alpha Yes it's still possible to download the latest SDK *and* XCode 3.2.6 http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=20792

Comment: Your normal frameworks are foundation, uikit, and one more, they end in .framework. Right click on the frameworks folder that contains them and add iAd to the project if it's not already there.

Comment: @JoePasq: i have already checked it and the iAd.framework is present in the frameworks folder of my code. There is no problem with this...